# Json Gson binding not working (Exception object / String)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm having some trouble parsing a JSON that I obtain from my DB to my Java (Android) Application. I hope you can help me out:

This is the Json that I have:

```
<br>
[{<br>
  "ID" : "1",<br>
  "name" : "Test name",<br>
  "type" : "1",<br>
  "Desc" : "blablabla",<br>
  "minNum" : "0",<br>
  "maxNum" : "12",<br>
  "Num" : "8",<br>
  "bool1" : "0",<br>
  "bool2" : "1",<br>
  "bool3" : "1",<br>
  "date" : "2012-04-01 23:00:00",<br>
  "double1" : "39.47208",<br>
  "doubl2" : "-0.3556063",<br>
  "someText" : "ajayeah",<br>
  "number" : "15",<br>
  "anotherNumber" : "1234"<br>
}, {"ID" : "2",<br>
  "name" : "Test name",<br>
  "type" : "1",<br>
  "Desc" : "blablabla",<br>
  "minNum" : "0",<br>
  "maxNum" : "12",<br>
  "Num" : "8",<br>
  "bool1" : "0",<br>
  "bool2" : "1",<br>
  "bool3" : "1",<br>
  "date" : "2012-04-01 23:00:00",<br>
  "double1" : "39.47208",<br>
  "doubl2" : "-0.3556063",<br>
  "someText" : "ajayeah",<br>
  "number" : "15",<br>
  "anotherNumber" : "1234"<br>
}]<br>
```

(The names are ovbiously not the ones I wrote here :P)

I have all that as a String (checked, OK), for example in a variable called responseString;

and then I've tried all possible ways to do the conversion but it always fails. I've tried to get it as an Object removing '[' ']', as an Array (things I achieved but then this line fails):

```
MyClassList MyClas = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, MyClassList.class);
```

The error is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

(with other tests converting it first to object or array, the error is with BEGIN_STRING)

Could it be because I'm using booleans, and Calendar type (in Date) and it's not supported by Gson library?

Well, I hope you can get my out of here because I'm going mad.

Thanks :)

---

Don't use Calendar, that was my problem. Instead, you may use Date and it works. Also, I don't know why, booleans like "0"|"1" don't work. Like "true"|"false" yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to deserialize an array into a class that is not an array, and that won't work for obvious reasons. Since you know the array type just use any instance of MyClass[] to get the class from. You can create one at any time. Alternately pass in `MyClass[].class` (i.e `MyClass.class` is not the same as `MyClass[].class`)

Here is an example that will run out of the box if you create a log4j.properties file (Or convert the loggers to System outs:

```
package com.techtrip.test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonTest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GsonTest.class);

    static ToSerialize t1 = new ToSerialize("1", "Test 1");
    static ToSerialize t2 = new ToSerialize("2", "Test 2");

    static ToSerialize target[] = {t1,t2} ;


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Gson gson = new Gson(); 

        String jsonStr = gson.toJson(target);

        logger.info(String.format("Target As String\n: %s", jsonStr));

        // This will work as well --> ToSerialize test[] = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, target.getClass());
        ToSerialize test[] = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, ToSerialize[].class);

        for (ToSerialize deserialized: test){
            logger.info(String.format("From JSON\n: %s", deserialized.toString()));
        }
    }

}

class ToSerialize implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String iD;
    private String name;


    public ToSerialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ToSerialize(String iD, String name) {
        super();
        this.iD = iD;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getiD() {
        return iD;
    }
    public void setiD(String iD) {
        this.iD = iD;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((iD == null) ? 0 : iD.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ToSerialize other = (ToSerialize) obj;
        if (iD == null) {
            if (other.iD != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!iD.equals(other.iD))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ToSerialize [iD=" + iD + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I receive the Json in a String, well formed as the structure I wrote before, but doing this:
MyClass test[] = gson.fromJson(responseString, MyClass[].class);

Doesn't work.

Finally I'm writting a parser by myself because I don't seem to get it working like this.

Thanks for you answer although it didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, stupid phone cut my response. Did you try doing it inline like in my example and compare the json strings? You shouldn't have to write your own parser as that could limit compatibility. Might make the dates transient our remove then as a test.

Comment: Yes, I'm on it, but yes. The sctructure of the Json is the same (except for the names, but they match the class ones). Now I'm gonna try to change to Date my Calendar, and rip out every strange character (ú). I'll tell you what happend in a few mins

Comment: Ok, tested. My 2 problems now are:
- It works if I change from Calendar to Date. 
Any idea on how to solve this? I thought Date was deprecated.
- Booleans as "0"|"1" seem not to be parsed correcly (always false). I get them from the response like that (not "true"|"false" as the do work), any ideas on this one too?

Comment: 1 other thing the exception should tell you what character it is puking on. it will be in the form of a column number. so if it dies before the date for you know it's not the date field

Comment: okay for that's good date isn't deprecated but a lot of the fields are. what I typically do however is I replace all my dates with the joda library. I'm assuming you probly can't control that it's coming in as calendar objects. in that case what I might try is just simply define mean the field as a string and then I would add a g e t t e r 2 convert it to a calendar date after the whole object has been instantiated.

Comment: I didn't had trouble with characters. Let me see if I got that right. I define the calendar as String (and as well as the booleans for what I said) and then, when it comes to use them, I convert them to Clanedar/boolean.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I know this is my third answer but as you can see the issue is so complicated because of the Calendar that multiple answers exist.

Using GSON will not work out of the box. I highly recommend dropping the Calendar and moving to JODA for reasons stated earlier.

The problem you are dealing with is a matter of serialization on the dates. Luckily, GSON allows you to register custom serializers for this purpose (another reason not to use your own parser). You can write one for Calendar or look for one that already has been written.

Thankfully this has already been done for JODA DateTimes and offers a blue print for those of you that want to write your own.

See here: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-type-adapters-for-common-classes

I implemented it as so:

```
package com.techtrip.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class DateTimeTypeConverter  implements JsonSerializer<DateTime>, JsonDeserializer<DateTime>  {
      // No need for an InstanceCreator since DateTime provides a no-args constructor
      @Override
      public JsonElement serialize(DateTime src, Type srcType, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
      }
      @Override
      public DateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context)
          throws JsonParseException {
        return new DateTime(json.getAsString());
      }
}
```

Perfect, so now all you have to do is register it with a GSON builder and drop it in as a replacement for your target class (in this case DateTime.class). This will thus serialize each DateTime using this class. Quite brilliant really.

Here is how to use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeTypeConverter());

    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    String jsonStr = gson.toJson(target);

    logger.info(String.format("Target As String\n: %s", jsonStr));

    // This will work as well --> ToSerialize test[] =
    // gson.fromJson(jsonStr, target.getClass());
    ToSerialize test[] = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, ToSerialize[].class);

    for (ToSerialize deserialized : test) {
        logger.info(String.format("From JSON\n: %s",
                deserialized.toString()));
    }

    String testString = "[{\"ID\" : \"1\",\"name\" : \"Test name\",\"type\" : \"1\",\"Desc\" : \"blablabla\",\"minNum\" : \"0\",\"maxNum\" : \"12\",\"Num\" : \"8\",\"bool1\" : \"0\",\"bool2\" : \"1\",\"bool3\" : \"1\",\"date\" : \"2012-04-08T07:50:01.600-05:00\",\"double1\" : \"39.47208\",\"doubl2\" : \"-0.3556063\",\"someText\" : \"ajayeah\",\"number\" : \"15\",\"anotherNumber\" : \"1234\"}, {\"ID\" : \"2\",\"name\" : \"Test name\",\"type\" : \"1\",\"Desc\" : \"blablabla\",\"minNum\" : \"0\",\"maxNum\" : \"12\",\"Num\" : \"8\",\"bool1\" : \"0\",\"bool2\" : \"1\",\"bool3\" : \"1\",\"date\" : \"2012-04-08T07:50:01.600-05:00\",\"double1\" : \"39.47208\",\"doubl2\" : \"-0.3556063\",\"someText\" : \"ajayeah\",\"number\" : \"15\",\"anotherNumber\" : \"1234\"}]";

    ToSerialize test2[] = gson.fromJson(testString, ToSerialize[].class);

    for (ToSerialize deserialized : test2) {
        logger.info(String.format("From JSON\n: %s",
                deserialized.toString()));
    }
}
```

There are some caveats and you will have to figure this out. First you will have to include a fully qualified date time format such as `2012-04-08T07:50:01.600-05:00`.

Second you will need a `DateTimeFormatter` such as the many provided by JODA to print these out. You can also get Calendar's from JODA if you desire.

I am sure with some work this can be done for Java's Calendar as well. Someone probably has already tackled it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I wanted to add the following as a comment but it is too long. Ok, I think I know what causes this. Looking at the exception `"Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"` this happens in one of two ways as Gson peeks to get the next value. BEGIN_OBJECT is represented by `{` and BEGIN_ARRAY is `[`.

For some reason the parser is treating your JSON string as if it starts as follows: `"[[{\"ID\"`

This can happen when coming in through javascript or something that truly is adding the extra brackets in an attempt to escape it as JSON when it already is in JSON format.

Sure enough when I change my string to be setup in that manner I get:

`Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3`

You didn't post the whole exception but I have seen conversions like this happen. My fear would be that you would write your own JSON parser when the parser is not the problem.

================ Original Answer Below ===================

I modified my original class above to mirror your JSON string and it works just fine. I am not on Android and perhaps you are catching something to specifically be causing your problems in that environment. If Date was a problem you woild get unparseable date as a JSON exception, which is the case on my setup where `"2012-04-01 23:00:00"` fails but `Apr 7, 2012 3:07:40 PM` does not.

Here is how it looks:

```
    String testString = "[{\"ID\" : \"1\",\"name\" : \"Test name\",\"type\" : \"1\",\"Desc\" : \"blablabla\",\"minNum\" : \"0\",\"maxNum\" : \"12\",\"Num\" : \"8\",\"bool1\" : \"0\",\"bool2\" : \"1\",\"bool3\" : \"1\",\"date\" : \"Apr 7, 2012 3:07:40 PM\",\"double1\" : \"39.47208\",\"doubl2\" : \"-0.3556063\",\"someText\" : \"ajayeah\",\"number\" : \"15\",\"anotherNumber\" : \"1234\"}, {\"ID\" : \"2\",\"name\" : \"Test name\",\"type\" : \"1\",\"Desc\" : \"blablabla\",\"minNum\" : \"0\",\"maxNum\" : \"12\",\"Num\" : \"8\",\"bool1\" : \"0\",\"bool2\" : \"1\",\"bool3\" : \"1\",\"date\" : \"Apr 7, 2012 3:07:40 PM\",\"double1\" : \"39.47208\",\"doubl2\" : \"-0.3556063\",\"someText\" : \"ajayeah\",\"number\" : \"15\",\"anotherNumber\" : \"1234\"}]";

    ToSerialize test2[] = gson.fromJson(testString, ToSerialize[].class);

    for (ToSerialize deserialized : test2) {
        logger.info(String.format("From JSON\n: %s",
                deserialized.toString()));
    }
```

Here is the Output:

```
ToSerialize [ID=2, name=Test name, Desc=blablabla, minNum=0, maxNum=12, Num=8, bool1=false, bool2=false, bool3=false, date=Sat Apr 07 15:07:40 CDT 2012, double1=39.47208, doubl2=-0.3556063, someText=ajayeah, number=15, anotherNumber=1234]
```

And here is the class definition (abridged) I even threw in a Boolean for grins)

```
class ToSerialize {
    int ID;
    String name;
    String Desc;
    int minNum;
    int maxNum;
    int Num;
    Boolean bool1;
    boolean bool2;
    boolean bool3;
    Date date;
    double double1;
    double doubl2;
    String someText;
    int number;
    int anotherNumber;
    ......
```

By all accounts this should work.

I am using the latest 2.1 version of GSON. This could be a bug somewhere as it should work for you.

Comment: Ive already wrote my parser, but I'm gonna try to see if this can solve the problem I was having and may help somebody else with this problem. I'll let you know as soon as I'm done testing your new answer. Thanks for your time, very appreciated :)

Comment: I'm using the same version as you (2.1), copied your answer into my project and it works although booleans should be defined as "true"|"false" not "0"|"1"
Another thing is I use Calendar, not Date, and if I change to Calendar, that throws the exception (even I if  change format from the Json).

If I can get to solve that I'll use it and save my own parser just in case.

I really appreciate your help, thank you very much again for your time and effort.

Comment: Oh man, there is so much to cover on that topic. As you have found out Dates are difficult to deal with. The problem is going between human readable form, which you have and machine time. You also don't have a time zone or an apparent calendar system in your String. (This is why Date works although likely will be incorrect) Dates are very complicated. In the Spring world I use the Jackson JSON parser that just happens to have a DateTime Serializer for doing such things. It's not trivial.

See here to see why this is such a complicated problem: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Comment: As an aside: Java's Calendar and Date API's are VERY poorly implemented. This is why 3pls like JODA exist and more importantly, JSR310 (called Three Ten), which will hopefully replace the built in Java Date and Calendar api's. The 310 effort is being led by the guy that wrote JODA so you can expect that it will improve on some deficiencies in JODA (like DateTime being a readable instant when it shouldn't be). That being said, JODA is a big improvement. 

Thanks for marking the question as answered. - Trip

Comment: Man, so much! The booleans should work with both true|false and 0|1.

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking so much time on me and my question. Cheers